# Where should the LES (light ethereum subprotocol) capability be sent and what is it's id?

Tags: light-clients, protocol

Is the LES subprotocol a wire protocol like (ETH, SHH) or is it an ETH subprotocol?

If it is an ETH subprotocol, it is not mentioned in https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Wire-Protocol as a subprotocol. What is the correct number to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Subprotocol, aka 'capability' , is a subprotocol of devp2p wire protocol.